# PostGIS validate the Z continuity

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d

What is the solution to validate if a 3D linestring is always going down? All linestring nodes must have a lower value than the previous one, to check if Z values in a line are going down continuously ... It is to validate the continuity of water lines.

Comment: How do you want the results; a selection of invalid LineStrings, vice versa, or an update of e.g. a boolean field?

Comment: I need to know which vertex is wrong and then correct it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the *LineStrings* are digitized in the correct order (start point is most elevated), running

```
SELECT ln_id,
       vtx_id,
       geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ln.<id> AS ln_id,
         dmp.path[1] AS vtx_id,
         dmp.geom,
         ST_Z(dmp.geom) < LAG(ST_Z(dmp.geom)) OVER(PARTITION BY ln.<id> ORDER BY dmp.path[1]) AS is_valid
  FROM   <lines> AS ln,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(ln.geom) AS dmp
) q
WHERE NOT is_valid
;
```

returns all vertices `geom`, their respective line `<id>`, and their position in the vertices array of that line, for all vertices with higher Z value as their predecessor.

For more information on the actual elevation (Z values) of the current vertex and its predecessor, run sth. like

```
SELECT ln_id,
       vtx_id,
       vtx_elev,
       pre_elev,
       geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ln.<id> AS ln_id,
         dmp.path[1] AS vtx_id,
         dmp.geom,
         ST_Z(dmp.geom) AS vtx_elev,
         LAG(ST_Z(dmp.geom)) OVER(PARTITION BY ln.<id> ORDER BY dmp.path[1]) AS pre_elev
  FROM   <lines> AS ln,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(ln.geom) AS dmp
) q
WHERE  vtx_elev > pre_elev
;
```

Comment: Wrote this from the top of my head, may need some corrections; e.g. not sure right now if the first vertex will get `NULL` or  `FALSE` assigned.

Comment: Tested and verified, working as expected.

Comment: Confirmed! Tested and verified, working as expected. Thanks @geozelot!!!!

Comment: @user88753 Good to hear. If this answer helped you/solved your issue, consider upvoting and accepting it (up-arrow and check mark next to the question body).